# XMLHttpRequest to scrape data from websites

Tags: html, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Hi I was hoping someone could help me get this code working I'm trying to make a web scraper script that I can launch from an button. Been searching through the forums for a couple of hours and so far I have come up with this:

```
function GetData()  {
  Var URL = "http://www.livescore.cz/"
  var XMLReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

  XMLReq.open( "GET", "https://edition.cnn.com/", false )
  XMLReq.send();

  XMLReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(XMLReq.readyState == 4 && XMLReq.status == 200) {
      alert(XMLReq.responseText);
    }
  }
}
```

But I guess I most have done something wrong. Any help would be much appreciated

frederik

Comment: `XMLReq.send();` shoud be after `XMLReq.onreadystatechange` part...

Comment: I can spot three things that would cause it to fail at a glance… and two of them would have very obvious error messages in the console of your browser's developer tools. Open the console. Read the error messages.

Comment: You where right I didn't think about checking there. Ill keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listener before the event fired.

```js
function GetData()  {
  var XMLReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

  XMLReq.open( "GET", "https://edition.cnn.com/", false )


  XMLReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(XMLReq.readyState == 4 && XMLReq.status == 200) {
      alert(XMLReq.responseText);
    }
  }

  XMLReq.send();
}

document.querySelector("#getDataBtn").addEventListener('click', GetData);
```

```html
<button id="getDataBtn">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply , little funny about web page you posted . was gona use the same in my sample , but in the end I decided to use the one im actually gonna try an scrape ..

Comment: I just picked your code and fixed it that is why is looks the same. :)

Comment: NIce thanks a lot. Just hope you don't mind one quick follow up question. How would I lunch this from an button,? the way its now the code gets triggered when the web pages opens

Comment: Great Thanks a lot again